# Path object transformation bug on Android 4?

Tags: android

I am using the next lines of code to transform Path object and draw it on the screen:

```
bitmapPath.addRect(bitmapRectF, Path.Direction.CW);     
bitmapPath.transform(bitmapMatrix);
```

When my targetSDK is set to 7 this code works just fine on Android 4, but when I set it to 15, path is NOT transformated at all by matrix specified in the method. 
An Android 3.2 everything works also fine even with targetSDK set to 15. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was that when I set targetSDK to 15 I enabled hardware acceleration mode in my app and it seems that bug exists only in these conditions.

So the solution: 
1. Set build target in project to Android 4.0.3
2. Disable hardware acceleration mode in your manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
</application>
```